# Creating a "custom" Caladbolg

Tags: final-fantasy-10

I've pretty much spent an hour each day trying to get the Sun Sigil for Tidus, doing the Catcher Chocobo minigame and the closest I've been overall is 7.5 seconds. I'm kinda fed up with it, and if I can't get the platinum because of this, so be it.

I was checking out the Caladbolg's abilities (Break Damage Limit, Triple Overdrive, Evade & Counter, Magic Counter). Those four abilities are possible to customize on a 4-slot sword for Tidus (60 Dark Matter, 30 Winning Formula, 1 Teleport Sphere, 16 Shining Gem), and I feel like I'd be able to get all of the materials much easily compared to how much time I've wasted trying to get a time of under 0 seconds with the minigame.

My (probably dumb) question is, would the game allow me to customize a weapon like that exactly? Would it also be renamed the Caladbolg automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately not.

Celestial weapons have a unique name and appearance. They also have unique damage formulas that ignore enemy defense and are based on the character's HP or MP (in Tidus's case, he deals more damage the closer he is to max hp).

The custom Caladbolg would have the abilities you put on it but would have the appearance and name of Excalibur (from Break Damage Limit) and would use the standard damage formula instead of Caladbolg's.

Comment: Oops, completely forgot about the special damage formula that's thrown in with each Celestial Weapon. Thanks for that heads up.

Comment: @LOL.NO. Note that the special damage formula for Caladblog is actually a penalty modifier: http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Caladbolg So you'll definitely want to use a weapon from Penance in the end anyway, see here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/210111/what-are-the-dominant-weapon-armor-configurations/215819#215819