# What abilities from celestial weapons can't be duplicated?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

Near the end game you can buy weapons from Rin which have 4 blank slots. Looking over what I need to do to get Tidas's Celestial Weapon and a Crest for Kimari's I thought that maybe it might be easier to just re-create the weapons by using the Customize command and the weapons brought from Rin.

So I am wondering, out of all the Celestial Weapons, which abilities out of them can't I duplicate (because ability can not be created or that the items required are so limited it's not possible)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a "custom" Caladbolg](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/166728/creating-a-custom-caladbolg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the abilities can be placed on an empty 4-slot weapon; however, they won't truly match the [Celestial Weapons](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Celestial_Weapon):

> While the game's Customization feature makes it possible for players to manually create weapons with the same abilities as the Celestial Weapons, any such weapons will not take on the Celestial Weapons' names. They will not ignore defense, won't have any effect on aeons (is refered to obtain them and not to equip them to characters), nor have the damage vary in different circumstances.