# What Are the Dominant Weapon/Armor Configurations?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

I'm playing through Final Fantasy X HD Remaster (which should be the same as the FFX International.)

I wondered is there an accepted dominant Weapon/Armor configuration? As far as the best abilities to apply to the slots. It seems like the Ultimate Weapons do not necessarily have the best load-out.

Comment: For a complete guide on armour and weapon customization I recommend [this one](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/197344-final-fantasy-x/faqs/37533)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a question about dominant weapon/armor configurations it is assumed that you're already finished with your Capture weapon and that you've already completed your sphere grid using a Triple A` weapon, so neither of those abilities are going to be considered.

Also note that since abilities *cannot* be removed your best bet is always getting a 4-slot drop that has the most costly abilities already on it.

You definitely want armor with Break HP Limit, since that's the most expensive you'll want to fight monsters that drop 4-slot weapons that already have the Break HP Limit ability. This is best obtained from [Dark Bahamut](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Bahamut_(Final_Fantasy_X)) because he may also apply Auto-Protect or Ribbon to the armors.

I break with the greater population here, and suggest that you do *not* use Auto-Remedy, Auto-Potion, or Auto-Phoenix on your armors, as money for the monster arena *will* be a factor late game and these abilities only increase the cost of battles (they also shorten the time though because you do not have to take turns to esuna/cure/life your party members, so take my comment with a grain of salt.)

So, armor abilities listed in order of importance:

1. Break HP Limit (obtained with the armor)
2. Auto-Haste (80 Chocobo-Wings use [the Machea trick](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/197344-final-fantasy-x/46790515#3))
3. Auto-Protect (obtained with the armor or 70 Light-Curtains overkill Fafnir for 40)
4. Master Thief (Rikku's armor only! 30 Pendulums bribe Ultima Weapon for 99)
5. Ribbon (On your First Strike character only! 99 Dark Matters you get these from the Monster Arena Trainer)
6. Auto-Regen (All other characters! 80 Healing Springs overkill Kottos for 40)

You definitely want weapons with Break Damage Limit, but you'll only want to use weapons obtained from Penance because those weapons have a hidden critical hit chance of 10% versus the 3% chance of most weapons.

Auron, Wakka, Kimahri, Tidus and Rikku's weapons:

1. Break Damage Limit (obtained with the weapon)
2. Evade & Counter (1 Teleport Sphere bribe Barbatos for 20)
3. Magic Counter (16 Shining Gems bribe Puroboros for 36)
4. Gillionare (Rikku's weapon only! 30 Designer Wallets you get these from the Monster Arena Trainer)
5. First Strike (On your Ribbon character only! 1 Return Sphere they are a rare drop from Barbatos so try to save one of these)
6. One MP Cost (Your other 2 characters! 20 Three Stars bribe Behemoth King for 14)

Yuna and Lulu's weapons:

1. Break Damage Limit (obtained with the weapon)
2. Magic Booster (30 Turbo Ether bribe Exoray for 30)
3. Magic +20% (4 Supreme Gems bribe Halma for 20)
4. One MP Cost (20 Three Stars bribe Behemoth King for 14)

**EDIT:**

I initially thought that Celestial Weapons had a bonus modifier on all damage done by the weapon, it turns out it's a penalty modifier. The penalty modifier uses a `RATIO` of either `CurrentHP / MaximumHP` or `CurrentMP / MaximumMP` in an equation like this:

```
(10 + 100 * RATIO) / 110
```

As you can see if `RATIO` is less than 1 this actually *reduces* the damage dealt. The only exception to this is Auron's Celestial Weapon which looks like this:

```
(130 - 100 * CurrentHP / MaximumHP) / 60
```

So when Auron's HP is above 70% this is a penalty modifier, but when Auron's HP is below 70% this is actually a bonus modifier. That being said when Auron's Strength stat is maxed out he will do 99,999 damage to anything even without the modifier, and since his Celestial Weapon has disappointing abilities it should be traded in for the dominant weapon recommended above.

Weapons are a bit more complex, the problem is that the Celestial Weapons have [additional damage calculations](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Celestial_Weapon), so a significant amount of work has to go into constructing a weapon that will have only moderately stronger damage. The real benefit from the reconfiguration is the abilities *on* the weapon. So because Tidus and probably Lulu's Celestial Weapons are so close to the weapon that I would suggest for them I recommend retaining their Celestial Weapons.

Comment: Break HP limit is the most overrated armor affix in the game. There is not a single enemy in the game that can 9999 your entire party if you have your stats maxed.

Comment: @Kevin The benefit of this would simply be more time for fighting, less time focused on healing. Maybe this isn't the way to go? I did ask the question to get advice, so if you have a recommendation, please share!

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, I didn't see you asked the question as well. What most people seem to do is basically what Joao Victor listed. With sufficient defense stats, I believe penance can 9998 the entire party (immediately countered by auto-potion).

Comment: @Kevin There are a lot of examples of enemies that do 9,999 damage to a single party member irrespective of defense or magic defense (King Cactular and Earth Eater for example.) Break HP Limit is certainly helpful for this.

Comment: Yes but auto-phoenix counters this. Break HP limit is certainly useful if you don't know what you're doing, but it's far from necessary and there are better alternatives.

Comment: With maxed stats, there are still things that do do 99,999 damage, like nemesis but you can cast auto life on yourself to counter. As for BHPL, it is not needed at all and a waste of slot on the armor. On armor you should have auto-haste/phoenix/protect and Ribbon. You can acquire Ribbon armor from Dark Aeons, Dark Yojimbo is the easiest one and you can repeat the process easily. Monster arena guy also gives you 99 dark matters which is 1 Ribbon. Celestial weapon will do the trick, with max stats, you will rarely not do 99,999 damage with 1 hit. There is no need for Master thief at all.

Comment: Also money should not be a factor, by the time you farmed max stats and whatever else you needed, you will be full of money. Master thief is useless because you should not depend on stealing to farm items. Ribbon is the most useful thing after auto haste, as it prevents almost all status ailments.

Comment: @Huangism I've been waiting to update this while I grind to a point where I can make a determination. I'll be updating at some point...

Comment: Once you hit max stats, almost everything becomes really really easy, even Dark Yojimbo's drops are good, probably the easiest way to get Ribbon on armor

Answer (score 5):

For armors I'd say:

- Auto Phoenix
- Auto Protect
- Auto Haste
- See below

Auto phoenix for auto reviving your characters (this uses phoenix downs first, and if you're out, mega-phoenixes are used).
Auto protect for auto protect status (dispel can't even remove it).
Auto Haste for those extra turns before the enemy.

The 4th slot depends: Auto-Potion and X-Potions are a great combination. Some people use Ribbon.

For weapons i'd say:

- Break damage limit
- Evade and counter
- Magic counter
- Armor Piercing

Break damage limit and armor piercing for those basic attacks and limit breaks over 9999 damage.
Evade and counter for dodging physical attacks. Even if it fails, you still do the basic attack.
And Magic Counter for countering if you were struck by magic.

But then again, it depends on what you'll be fighting I guess.

Comment: Break Damage limit is a weapon skill.  I believe you may have a typo.  But you should also mention *why* you would use these skills; that would elevate this to a great answer.

Comment: @Frank Edited my answer.

Comment: That helps.  I cleaned it up a bit for you, and hopefully fixed the typo.

Comment: @JoaoVictor So you'd recommend this for every character, not so much a character specific armor or weapon?

Comment: @JonathanMee well, my main trio were Tidus, Wakka and Auron...so these skills suited me just fine. I didn't use Kimahri and Lulu as much. Yuna was a pretty solid caster (healing or dealing damage) not to mention her aeons. So i used the same equipment for her as well. For her weapons i used 1 mp cost and first strike on her. But then again, those worked for me. There's some trial and error on creating these weapons. Lost the count of how many times i got destroyed by those dark aeons and creatures from the arena xD.

Comment: @JoaoVictor That seems to be good advice. I tended to use Tidus, Wakka, and Auron against Omega Weapon in the North America release, I was just wondering how much had changed.

Comment: @JonathanMee If i remember correctly, omega weapon is not that difficult. I had more trobules with the monsters at the arena.

Comment: @JoaoVictor You're right, I meant Nemesis, not Omega Weapon.

Comment: Celestial weapons will do the trick, there is no point making your own, except for Lulu's because it's so hard to get. For armor Ribbon as the 4th ability is best as it prevents almost all status ailments. Without first strike on a weapon and Ribbon on armor, you an get ambushed by Malboro thing and get confused and wipe easily.

Answer (score 2):

If you are making a weapon and armor that is the "best" for dealing damage while surviving fights, there are a few things to consider first.

Weapon
req. Break Damage Limit-so you can actually hit for 99,999
opt. Everything else-though here are some of the better choices.
opt. First Strike-situational-for lower level enemies.
opt. Counterattack/Evade and Counter/Magic Counter-VERY useful for bonus hits.
opt. 1 MP cost/Mana Booster-great for casting or using abilities like Quick Hit
opt. Triple AP/Triple Overdrive-Situational for farming AP, though Triple Overdrive is great as a standard damage dealer
opt. Status/Elemental Strikes-1 shot KOs, but what for at this point?

The key for a winning piece of armor relies on knowing what you're fighting. If you're in Omega Ruins, you will need some confuse/stoneproof armor, as Malboros and Demon walls can end your game fast. Penance, Nemesis, Dark Aeons-require auto-abilites so that when you do die, you can recover instantly. Hard to kill your party with auto-life and reraise. NOTHING in the game requires Break-HP limit, though it is pretty to get to 99,999, and makes some fights easier. You can sub out Auto-Protect for this if you want, then add Ribbon as your 4th slot.
Armor
req. Auto-Haste-never lose your speed
req. Auto-Phoenix-second chance, as long as someone is alive
req/opt. Auto-Protect-halved damage always
opt. Break-HP Limit-high HP numbers
opt. Ribbon-status immunity
opt. Proof skills-deathproof/stoneproof-but why not use Ribbon instead?
opt. Auto-Shell, Auto-Regen-great for survivability

Personally, I go with Auto-Haste, Auto-Phoenix, Ribbon, Auto-Shell-and Break Damage, Triple Overdrive, 1 MP cost, Counterattack.
You get super defenses, infinite haste and reraise, Overdrive spam and cheap quick attacks.

Answer (score 1):

For armors, I used Break HP Limit, Auto-Haste, Ribbon, and Auto-Phoenix to kill Penance, and only Auto-Haste and Auto-Phoenix were really essential.  Stone proof would suffice instead of ribbon, and BHL was more useful for farming Dark Yojimbo for a bunch of Dark Matters/BHL+Ribbon armors than it was for the final battle.

As for the best weapons?  It's the Celestial ones, no argument.  Yeah, some of their abilities are kind of mediocre, and after you max the Sphere Grid the Double AP ability on some of them is just insulting.  And yes, they do have funky damage calculations, which you might care about when farming Earth Eater for fortune spheres, but none of that matters.  The Celestial Weapons all have a hidden property that cannot be duplicated via synthesis, it ignores the defense stat of the target (except when used for limit breaks, which is fine because Quick Hit).

Someone tested it and posted their results [here](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/197344-final-fantasy-x/56025562).