# For Stat Maxing Should I Just Maximize Luck?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

This is a question about maximizing Luck and doing away with all Evasion and Accuracy.

A good answer to this question would be supported by the following:

1. What is the formula for calculating a hit?
2. What is the formula for calculating a critical hit?
3. What is the formula for calculating an evasion?
4. Which enemy has the maximum stat contribution to each of these formulas? (presumably Penance)

Armed with these formulas I think it would be pretty easy answer whether I need any Evasion or Accuracy at all, should I reach 255 Luck.

Comment: [relevant](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/197344-final-fantasy-x/faqs/46942)

Comment: @Kevin Sounds like some of an answer? "255 Luck = 255 Accuracy + 255 Evasion

 Having 255 Luck + 255 Accuracy isn't needed because you can basically hit
  anything with 255 Luck alone and it will do critical.

 Having 255 Luck + 255 Evasion isn't needed because the higher level bosses can
  hit you regardless of these stats. Yet, it's advisable to keep at least 30
  Evasion so that you can Evade all of Dark Ixion's physical attacks." No math to support it but it has numbers.

Comment: I have no idea if it's an answer, I didn't read it now, it's just the guide I used when maxing my stats waaaaaaaay back when. Damnit, I wanna play FFX again :(

Comment: @Kevin They re-released it for PS3/PS4/Vita! Now you can play it through again with me and get all the achievements, and figure out the answers to all my stat maxing questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1 - What is the formula for calculating a hit?
>
> 3 - What is the formula for calculating an evasion?

In addition to the guide Kevin linked in his comment, GameFAQs also has a [stat mechanics guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/197344-final-fantasy-x/faqs/31381) and an [enemy database](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/197344-final-fantasy-x/faqs/24166) that's helpful for this question.

Basically, Accuracy and Evasion are used to calculate the accuracy of the attack. To calculate the hit percentage from that, you add the attacker's luck and subtract the defender's luck - hence, the importance of Luck; it's added directly to (or subtracted from) the hit percentage, so every additional point of Luck is an additional increase / decrease.

In the end, the answer is that, even if your own Accuracy and Evasion are low, if your Luck is high enough, you should hit the enemy (and they should miss you) nearly all the time.

Two caveats in the equation:

1) When you're facing an enemy with similar Luck to your own, the original accuracy calculation value would dominate the final answer. A quick glance through the enemy database, however, shows only a few enemies with high Luck (mostly the Dark Aeons, especially Dark Bahamut, Dark Yojimbo, and Dark Mindy, who are each 100+). Even in those cases, if you max out Luck, the Hit% should be greater than 100 (attacking) or less than -100 (defending).

2) According to the enemy database, there are also plenty of enemy attacks that will apparently hit regardless of the Accuracy calculation.

---

> 2 - What is the formula for calculating a critical hit?

[According to a post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/197344-final-fantasy-x/58884801) on the GameFAQs forums, the Critical Hit formula is similar to the hit percentage:

```
Critical+ Value for attack + Attacker Luck - Target Luck
```

Again, if you max out Luck, then your Critical Hit % should rise to nearly 100%.

---

> 4 - Which enemy has the maximum stat contribution to each of these formulas? (presumably Penance)

According to the enemy database, it appears that Dark Mindy, with her 130 Luck, would be the enemy whose Luck stat would make it most difficult to hit and evade.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because mine is largely a duplicate of it which was posted a day latter, but there are a few clarifications in my answer which may be worth reading.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start by pointing out that Luck is the *most* difficult stat to achieve and should not be entered into lightly. You can only obtain Luck Spheres from Greater Sphere in the Monster Arena and you can only obtain the Fortune Spheres needed to unlock them from Earth Eater in the Monster Arena.

- Each of these costs $15,000 to fight and take ~2 minutes to defeat, as long as you overkill both you will obtain 2 Luck Spheres and 2 Fortune Spheres
- Those two pairs will net you +8 Luck for one character, you'll need an additional 12 Fortune Spheres to distribute the +8 luck to the rest of your party
- That's $15,000 and ~2 minutes to add 1 Luck to everyone in the party
- So maximizing Luck for all characters would cost $3,825,000 and take ~8.5 hours

**1. What is the formula for calculating a hit?**

Your Accuracy is compared to the attacker's Evasion And the output is crunched to a number in the range 0 to 10, call it `AccuracyPreLuck`. I don't wanna post the table cause I got from section IV of this document that has copyright requests: http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/197344-final-fantasy-x/faqs/31381

http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/197344-final-fantasy-x/51524696?page=1#18 says:

- For the attack to connect: `AccuracyPreLuck + AttackerLuck - TargetLuck > 75`
- If the attacker is blind: `AccuracyPreLuck + AttackerLuck - TargetLuck > 90`

**2. What is the formula for calculating a critical hit?**

- http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/197344-final-fantasy-x/58884801#2 says for a critical hit: `WeaponCritChance + AccuracyPreLuck + AttackerLuck - TargetLuck > 100`

**3. What is the formula for calculating an evasion?**

Again citing from [section IV of the document with copyright requests](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/197344-final-fantasy-x/faqs/31381) there is no special calculation for evasion, `EvasionPreLuck` for purposes of evasion is simply the target evasion minus to the attacker accuracy. And the same formulas apply:

- To guarantee a dodge: `EvasionPreLuck + AttackerLuck - TargetLuck < 0`
- If the attacker is blind: `EvasionPreLuck + AttackerLuck - TargetLuck < 15`

**4. Which enemy has the maximum stat contribution to each of these formulas?**

The highest `AttackerLuck` is Dark Mindy at: 130
The highest `AttackerAccuracy + AttackerLuck` is Dark Ixion at: 290

---

In summary:

- Accuracy is a worthless stat, 255 Accuracy = 10 Luck toward your hit calculations
- Evasion and Luck are interchangeable 1 Luck = 1 Evasion for your dodge calculations so maximize Luck for critical hits and then prefer the easier to obtain Evasion stat
- To achieve a critical on Dark Mindy when you have an Accuracy of 0, you'll need 230 Luck - `WeaponCritChance`
- If you follow [this advice for weapon crafting](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/215819/53654) your `WeaponCritChance` should be 10 so you'll only need 220 Luck to achieve a critical on Dark Mindy
- Yuna, Lulu, and Auron are tied for the lowest starting Luck at 17 so you'll only need to add 203 Luck to your sphere grid to achieve a critical on Dark Mindy with any character
- With a Luck of 220 to dodge Dark Ixion's attacks you'll need 70 evasion to guarantee a dodge
- Wakka, Kimahri, Rikku, and Auron all have only 5 starting Evasion so you'll need to add 65 Evasion to your sphere grid to guarantee a dodge of Dark Ixion's attacks

**Answer: The most effective sphere grid will contain 203 Luck, 65 Evasion, and 0 Accuracy.**